# Montmort’s matching problem with venn diagram

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

is it possible to have a venn diagram represent de Montmort matching problem where the number of cards is $n=3$ with the elements included in the diagram? 

I understand how inclusion/exclusion works(thanks to the kind contributors here) with $ \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i - \sum_{i<j} A_i \cap A_j + \sum_{i<j<k} A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k - \dots + (-1)^{n+1} A_i \cap \dots A_n$.


However, i can't picture where the elements are placed in the venn diagram with 6 permutations of $n=3$. Feel free to expand the $n$ value if it helps represent the matching problem via the venn diagram.

Kindly advise. Thank you

added* description of  Montmort’s matching problem

"Let there be $n$ objects numbered from 1 to $n$, and let them be ordered at random, assuming that the $n!$ permutations are equally probable. A coincidence occurs if object number $i$ is found at the $i$th place. The problem is to find the number of permutations with at least one coincidence or, equivalently, the probability of at least one coincidence...:"[A. Hald]

[quoted from rstudio](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/182862_f0918be6268740108a4c23235f33dbf0.html)

Comment: You need to tell us what Montmort's matching problem is (by [editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4428144/edit), not in the comments), because this is not common knowledge.

Comment: Seems you are asking about a derangement problem. And Venn Diagram is used to illustrate the relationship between various set - in probability we call them events. So you need to first determine the events you interested in to be shown in this Venn diagram. E.g. The events of card $1,2,3$ being matched. And then you place the singletons inside.

Comment: @ BGM, thank you for the reply. This is where is gets cloudy for me, there are $n=3$ with $n!$ permutations. If we use "pebble world" to describe the sample space, there are 3 pebbles and 6 sets within the space. [('1', '2', '3'),  ('1', '3', '2'), ('2', '1', '3'), ('2', '3', '1'),  ('3', '1', '2'), ('3', '2', '1')].  All the sets are overlapping, making it confusing for me to picture it in a venn diagram, hence, the question.

Comment: @Mike Earnest, thank you for the reply, i've added a shot description as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the finest Venn diagram that Windows paint can offer:

[image]